# Accessing a character in a string vs. converting to character array in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, char

In answering another question someone pointed out that in C# you can access a character in string by doing sting[i]. My question is, what is happening under the covers? Is this any different than converting the string to a character array and then parsing it?

I assume the difference is in memory usage and mutability but I'd rather know than assume :)

Comment: Read about Indexers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: A string *is* an array of characters.  You are directly accessing those individual characters.  This is why it's better to start by learning programming in C...

Comment: @mellamokb I learned C/C++ before C#, and I know what a string is. I'm curious about how this particular abstraction works. These are distinctly different types in C#.

Comment: This is the indexer in question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that converting to a character array will create a copy of the string's internal character array, whereas using the indexer will access the characters in place.

Comment: Is the string mutable? Can I do string[3] = "i";   ?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal No.  (Unless you use unsafe code and pointer manipulation, but that's generally a **very** bad idea.  Don't ever do that unless you're really, really sure you know what you're doing.)  You can just try to compile the code to see that it won't work.

Comment: @Servy I'll take your word for it. I'm unfortunately not in an environment where I can do that (in a lecture using OS X).